# SVG class with boilerplate prologue and epilogue from files

Tags: python, object-oriented, comparative-review, file, constructor

I noticed this old class of mine:

```
class SvgDrawing:

    def __init__(self, print_layout):
        self.print_layout = print_layout

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_start.txt'), mode='r') as f:
            self.svg_start = f.read()

        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_end.txt'), mode='r') as f:
            self.svg_end = f.read()
```

And I thought I would refactor it like this to avoid re-reading the same file every time an instance is created.

```
class SvgDrawing:

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_start.txt'), mode='r') as f:
        svg_start = f.read()

    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_end.txt'), mode='r') as f:
        svg_end = f.read()

    def __init__(self, print_layout):
        self.print_layout = print_layout
```

The new code works and improves the performance, but... something is telling me that there should be a better way.

Is it correct to put code that does something more complex than just assigning constant values in the class definition?

Comment: Here is a [good read](https://medium.com/@makmanalp/python-statements-in-the-body-of-a-class-63664392e062#.um041ny3z) on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to put code that does something more complex than just assigning constant values in the class definition?

In general, I try to avoid it. Any code in the class definition will be run as soon as the class definition is executed – that is, as soon as somebody imports your code. So putting complex code in the class definition causes problems for importers:

- If the code is slow, you slow down the rest of the program
- If the code has side effects, you’re breaking the rule of least surprise – it’s quite unusual for importing a module to have side effects
- If the code can throw exceptions (e.g. if you try to read `svg_start.txt` and it’s not there), same thing. When I import a library, the only exception I expect it might throw would be an `ImportError`. Throwing an `OSError` is generally quite unusual.

So I’d try to avoid it if you can. Only run that code when you need it – i.e., when somebody starts making instances of the class.

---

In this case, I’d think of maybe defining a descriptor, which caches the file contents, and then apply that to the class, like so:

```
class CachedFile:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.contents = None

    def __get__(self, instance, type):
        if self.contents is None:
            self.contents = open(self.path).read()
        return self.contents


class SVGDrawing:

    svg_start = CachedFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_start.txt'))
    svg_end = CachedFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'svg_end.txt'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Note that in this case, the file reads are deferred right up to the point where we need them – much more efficient than doing a read at import time. The flipside is that this code is a bit more complicated – you should decide if the performance gain is worth it.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Is there a way to do the same from __init__() without using the mutable list trick?

Comment: @stenci What mutable list trick?

Comment: Adding a mutable class member like `svg = []`,  then assigning the value in `__init__` with `svg[0] = txt`. `svg` hasn't changed, so it is still visible as a class member, its content has changed. It works, but it's hacky.